# how to change browser in live server plugin in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

when i wanna use live server in visual studio code automatically open with Microsoft edge but I wanna open it  with google chrome how I can fix this ?

Comment: what is your default browser, what are the settings of the extension

Comment: my defualt browser is google chrome but i cant find setting of the extension because I'm new to working with Visual Studio

Comment: VS or VSC what do you use?

Comment: 1 click and you can find the settings and there is one to change the browser